# Can I send files to my PC from the web without having to download them?

Tags: windows-7, google-chrome, firefox, browser, download

Is there any way I can transfer files from the web to my computer?

My Internet speed is too low, like 256kb/s download and I think 60kb/s upload. I was searching for a way to download files faster. I found a browser-testing site. I only have access to the browser itself, not the PC as a whole, so I tried a lot. Finally, I found a way: I signed up on pCloud and direct downloaded my file there from the browser testing site. I downloaded a 1 Gb file in 30 seconds, then I downloaded pCloud Drive onto my original PC.

I thought that since I have already downloaded the file to pCloud, I only have to copy and paste from pCloud drive to my original PC, but when I did that it said it would take 10 hours, and the speed was like 25kb/s. Then I realized that pCloud could not help.

Again I searched for browser testing sites or virtual PC web based drives. I found a site which can let me download anything from my browser, but I can't install TeamViewer or another program on their PC, just browser download.

I tried everything, like Chrome Remote Desktop, Zoho Assist in the Chrome Store, and all other online web-based remote PCs to transfer files, but nothing worked.

I then downloaded Airdroid on my Android, and sent my HTTP link to that browser testing, and it connected and I can send file but after 100% file complete it said “upload error”.

I then downloaded Xender, which is like Airdroid, and it also did not work.

I found another option on the Internet that says I can send big files. I uploaded a file there, but again my original PC has to download from there.

Is there any web-based way I can send files directly to my original PC, without my original PC having to download it?

Answer (score 4):

In short, no.

Think of it this way...
You want a ton of sand. There is a company with a depot 100 miles away. They have just the right sand at their main depot & a big, fast truck to deliver it.
Problem is that the truck cannot get through your gate, so they will have to dump the sand in the street outside.

You have a shovel & a wheelbarrow.

No matter how quickly they deliver the sand to the street, you will still have to shift it into your house one shovelful at a time.

Comment: there will be a way.I understand what u say and you explain me good but anything that work or transfer a file a little faster

Comment: Nope. You only have a shovel to get it in the gate, however fast it gets to the street. That's your speed limit. The only way round that is to buy a faster connection/bigger shovel.

Comment: thanks for explaining me but i will try more things to get that file there will be someway as u know there are too much ways in computer world

Answer (score 1):

What you're asking is working in the cloud.

Is it possible to work in the cloud, yes it is. Can I do whatever I want? No, there are limitations.

If you use google drive, you can open certain files in a web editor, such as word documents, excel documents, etc. You can even edit them. This means you can store them somewhere else without they ever being on your home pc.

If you need more freedom than this, it is possible to rent a virtual server or perhaps even build one and place it at a place with faster internet that gives you access. By remote control, you can then use that server, store files and even edit, play, view, etc with them on that location. The file will never be on your pc either.

That said, all above options will mean one simple thing, the moment you involve your home pc, you run into the same problem. Streaming files over the internet takes just as much bandwidth, in fact it takes more than to download it once. So in essence you will not be able to use this from your original pc at all.

If you somehow want the content to be on your original pc without downloading it there, then the only alternative is: download it somewhere else, and use a portable medium such as a USB harddrive or flashdrive and transfer it that way.

Comment: ok but if i buy a virtual sever the sever download speed will be same as my internet or it will be fast ?

Comment: The virtual server will have the speed of the internet it is connected to. Usually these are located at a datacenter with incredible speeds.

Comment: Haha no of course not. Renting a VPS is an expensive undertaking. They not only keep a pc powered for you, they supply internet access to it and give support. There is no free solution for your question. If you have a spare pc, you could maybe find a friend with faster internet and ask them if you may put it on their internet, but then they are paying for your hosting.

Comment: @AHMEDALI - I guess it's back to the shovel ;)

Comment: ok i got vps for free 1gb/s internet and full access to pc.But i try teamviewer and other remote control software they all transfer file with my download speed of my original pc.i also attach my usb and local drive to my vps but still it is copying files like 25kb/s and too slow.so I think there will be a software who transfer file without downloading them

Comment: You remote control the VPS and you download on the VPS, and you work with the files on the VPS. You cannot transfer the files to your own pc because the speed is not fast enough, nor is there a way you can change this. See the other answer as to why.

Comment: ok thanks but somehow i think there will be a possible way in future to do that.DON'T LOSE HOPE NOTHING IS IMPOSSIBLE

Comment: Of course there is. Get faster internet.