# SOFTWARE TO SHARE INTERNET

Tags: sharing

Hello as u know guys VPS internet connection is like hell lot of speed
is there any way i can share that internet connection to my original PC.
I saw many post but i can only share internet with hot-spot now hot-spot can't reach my house from VPS Data Center 
So is there anything like make money with internet connection or share vps internet connection with my original Pc.
there will be a way to share vps internet to original pc easily

Comment: So many questions so little question marks and clarity

Comment: Re: your earlier question... You still have a shovel.

Comment: yeah :) u r right but nothing is impossible :)

Comment: If there was a way to get 'faster internet' without having to actually buy a faster connection, then everybody would be doing it. As they are not, I think it's fairly safe to assume... it cannot be done.

Answer (score 2):

A VPS is located in a data center where someone pays a huge amount of money for one or more extremely fast Internet connections that the server machines use. Your "original PC" in your home is probably at the end of a relatively inexpensive, relatively slow Internet connection. The speed of the home broadband service you're paying for is the problem. If you paid a lot of money for say gigabit residential Internet service, your home PC would be able to do Internet things a lot faster too.

There's no magic way for your VPS to upgrade the quality of your broadband wiring or the broadband modems on both ends of your home Internet connection.

That said, it's possible that you're not getting the full benefit of your home Internet connection because you need a better modem or you have avoidable packet loss or bufferbloat problems. But that would be a whole separate question.

Comment: oh, there **was** a whole separate question :/ http://superuser.com/questions/1141098/can-i-send-files-to-my-pc-from-the-web-without-having-to-download-them to which this is merely part two of a major miscomprehension [read all the comments] - hence my shovel comment above.

Comment: yeah u are right but some way i think i will find some way to get benefit from vps which my pc can't do